# How should I split/improve this question so it is not too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I want to ask a question on the main site. This is the current draft:

> ### How does Time Stop interact with the duration of other spells?
>
> When someone casts [Time Stop](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/time-stop) (in this case an [Archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage)), they take turns while everyone else is stopped in time:
>
> > You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row
>
> I am having trouble determining how this is supposed to affect the duration of other spell effects. That is, whether these extra turns taken by the Archmage count towards the duration of spell effects that were already present at the time of casting.
>
> I am assuming (possibly wrongly) that the answer depends on the nature of the spell/effect. The main point that I want to know is what factors, if any, are used to determine wether a spell duration is affected. I have considered this (non-exhaustive) list of factors:
>
> 1. Whether the spell affects only the Archmage, only other creatures, both or no creatures at all.
> 2. Whether the spell was cast by the Archmage or someone else
> 3. Whether the spell is a concentration spell
> 4. Combinations of these factors
>
> Specific spells that I am concerned about (since they may come up during the encounter) include:
>
> 1. The Archmage's self casted [Mirror Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirror-image), [Globe of Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability)
> 2. The Archmage's [Banishment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) cast on an opponent
> 3. PC's [Blindness/Deafness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness), [Compelled Duel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/compelled-duel) cast on the Archmage or an Archmage's ally
> 4. PC's [Bless](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless) only on PCs
>
> So which factors are used to determine whether the extra turns one takes during Time Stop affect a particular spell?

This, to me, screams "too broad" for having way too many things to consider. 
It may also attract valid answers that simply say "this what happens with this spell or in this case in particular" which is not what I want.

On the other hand asking individual questions on the interaction of each of these spells with Time Stop seems excessive.

How should I solve this?

A question has been asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127555/33707) following [Rubiksmoose's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8149/33707)

Comment: Looking forward to a few more questions about Time Stop's interactions.  (One of the comments under my *bless* answer was about the *sequester* spell)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [sequester question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127730/33707) has been asked. I believe this is what you meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ask about one spell with a few different conditions at first

The assumption seems to be that you need to investigate different spells to figure out the different cases, but one spell can be used to investigate multiple conditions in one question easily.

For example, ask "How does Time Stop interact with the duration of bless?" but then in the body ask about the cases where it is cast:

- by the archmage
- by not the archmage
- only on the archmage
- only not on the archmage
- on archmage and others

By lowering it down to just one spell in different cases you greatly reduce the workload and the broadness. And even with just one spell you are going to get a lot of information that will help reduce the number of questions you have to ask, and possibly might answer them all.

**Best case:** you are going to get a general answer that happens to cover your other spells as well.

**Worst case:** you will answer 3/4 of your #1, all of #2, and probably #3 as well.

In the worst case, you have already greatly reduced the number of questions going forward. Not that asking multiple questions is even an issue!